# unable to select certain records in TSQL without using a range, between, etc

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing, sql-execution-plan, hint

On a SQL Server 2008 R2 database I have a table with a single integer as a primary key.  Sometimes when I perform a select on the primary key I get no results, but if I do a search for all records on the primary key between certain values I am able to retrieve the row.  This only affects a few records (less than ten out of millions of rows).  The vast majority of records can be selected with a simple "equals" statement.

Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix the problem?  I suspect something may be wrong with the clustered index.  If I use the hint "index(0)" then I can get the record without using a range.

**Details:**

Statement 1 produces no results:

```
select * from claim where claim_id = 12166769
```

Statement 2 produces one result for claim_id 12166769:

```
select * from claim where claim_id > 12166768 and claim_id < 12166770
```

Both statements use a Clustered Index Seek using PK_claim_claim_id.

Statement 3 produces one result for claim_id 12166769 using a hint:

```
select * from claim  with (index(0)) where claim_id = 12166769
```

The claim table has a column named "claim_id" defined as the primary key, integer, not null.  It has a clustered index on the primary key named "PK_claim_claim_id".

I'm using SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to view the Plan Tree.  Statement 1 has 1 Estimated Row and 0 Actual rows.  Statement 2 has 7 Estimated rows and 1 Actual row.

**Update**
Additionally we found that when we ran

```
select * from claim where claim_id > 12166774 and claim_id < 12166775
```

we came up five rows returned, 12166770 through 12166774.  Running

```
select * from claim with (index(0))  where claim_id > 12166774 
and claim_id < 12166775
```

with the hint returned no records as expected.

**6/22/2012 Update**

I spoke too soon.  We found this error in a different spot.  I found that I hadn't actually scanned the entire database, only a portion of it.

```
select * from claim where claim_id in (8223749,8223752,8223753,8223754,8223755)
```

returns no rows, while

```
select * from claim with (index(0))
    where claim_id in (8223749,8223752,8223753,8223754,8223755)
```

returns rows.  I ran

```
SELECT sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%),claim_id FROM claim with (index(0)) 
WHERE claim`_id in (8223749,8223752,8223753,8223754,8223755)
```

and received

```
(3:1394868:2)   8223749
(3:1394868:5)   8223752
(3:1394868:6)   8223753
(3:1394868:7)   8223754
(3:1394868:8)   8223755
```

Comment: DBCC CHECKTABLE 
(
    table_name | view_name
    [ , { NOINDEX | index_id }
     |, { REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD } 
    ] 
)

Comment: We have DBCC CHECKDB scheduled to run weekly and it reported no errors yesterday, we'll run DBCC CHECKTABLE tonight and see what it comes up with.

Comment: Only way I can think of debugging this would be to start at the index root and use either SQL Server Internals Viewer or `DBCC IND` and `DBCC PAGE` to follow the pointers down and see where it takes you.

Comment: What does `SELECT sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%),claim_id  FROM claim WHERE claim_id > 12166774 and claim_id < 12166775` say for the 5 rows returned?

Comment: We ran "dbcc checktable('claim')" last night to see what it would come up with and there were no errors found.  This morning when I tried to look at this problem some more I found out that it seems to be resolved.  The select statements are now returning the rows I would expect.

Comment: I ran SELECT sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) ,claim_id FROM claim WHERE claim_id >= 12166769  and claim_id <= 12166775 this morning and the results were (3:3154648:0) to (3:3154648:6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment seemed to fix the problem I will go ahead and post as an answer.

DBCC CHECKTABLE ( table_name | view_name [ , { NOINDEX | index_id } |, { REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD } ] )

Comment: Since we ran it without the repair flags would it still have fixed the problem?  Also we had ran been running DBCC CHECKDB and I think that should have caught it also.

Comment: I checked our entire database using a Perl script to select the set of claim ids and then select them individually to make sure they were all "selectable".  It seems like the problem is resolved across the entire database and I don't know what else could have resolved it so I'm tentatively marking this as the answer.  I appreciate the help from everyone.

Comment: To my knowledge if you don't use the repair it does not repair.  The only thing I can think of is a corrupt cache that got resolved but that is a reach.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing too, except when we looked back at some application logs we'd been the side effects of this error, for these entries, for two weeks.  If it was a corrupted cache it would have explained why adding the hint to not use the index would allow use to retrieve the rows when it failed otherwise.